# Meaning of とちゃうやろな (Kansai)

Tags: reading-comprehension, kansai-ben

[image]

Context: The character helps a girl off the street and upon bringing her home, he realizes this could mean trouble and this scenario comes up in his head.

The character speaks kansai and I'm having trouble telling what the sentence here means

> こんなんとちゃうやろな

I imagine こんなん is akin to to こんな but I'm stumbled on とちゃう then. やろな is just やろ+な

Answer (score 3):

とちゃう is technically from と違う but is used like じゃない. こんなんとちゃうやろな = こんなんじゃないだろうな

Comment: Since the OP is also guessing about こんなん, it might help to un-contract it to こんなの.

Comment: So like "this kind of thing, isn't it?"

Comment: @Kawase_K This じゃないだろな expresses the speaker's being afraid it's the case (it=こんなん here). Verbosely, *is it/he/she something like the second panel? I don't like that*.